# BadImageError while trying to upload image

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library

I am using Google App Engine server running on Python. My application has some file upload fields meant to upload images. And while I process the image, I am getting this error:

```
ERROR    2013-10-09 14:32:06,727 main.py:29] Exception in request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ajith/Dev/Space/SDK/google_appengine/lib/django-1.2/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ajith/Dev/Space/Space/src/space/company/views.py", line 172, in companyDetails
    thumbnail = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG)
  File "/home/ajith/Dev/Space/SDK/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/images/__init__.py", line 799, in execute_transforms
    return rpc.get_result()
  File "/home/ajith/Dev/Space/SDK/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 612, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/home/ajith/Dev/Space/SDK/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/images/__init__.py", line 886, in execute_transforms_hook
    raise _ToImagesError(e, self._blob_key)
BadImageError
```

This is where I am getting this error, while trying to execute transform:

```
img = images.Image(content)
img.resize(width=100, height=100)
img.im_feeling_lucky()
thumbnail = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG)
logo = db.Blob(thumbnail)
```

Any responses will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post code where you're getting "content". (I had such errors when I received image via urlfetch but it returned 404 or something like this with not-an-image content)

Comment: You better append it to the question

Comment: @Denisigo: This is the piece of code where I am getting the 'content' 

`if request.POST:
    content_type = None
    content = None
    for f, file_info in request.FILES.items():
        filename = file_info.name
        content_type = file_info.content_type
        content = file_info.read()
        if content and content_type:
            img = images.Image(content)
            img.resize(width=100, height=100)
            img.im_feeling_lucky()
            thumbnail = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG)
            logo = db.Blob(thumbnail)`